# Django Tutorial app, part 2. Why is missing - add field Question to Choice after makemigrations command?

Tags: python, django

I'm following the tutorial 2.2 Writing your first Django app, part 2. I created the models `Question` and `Choice` in the `polls/models.py` file like the tutorial.

```py
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I activated the poll app in the `mysite/settings.py` file.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Then i run the command makemigrations but in the output is missing "- Add field question to choice".

```py
$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice
```

I'm using the following versions:

```py
/mysite$ pip freeze
Django==2.2.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0

/mysite$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

I started the whole tutorial from scratch. Eliminating the project and starting another without success.

Comment: What do you mean by "I deleted all the project and start again without success"?

Comment: That I started the whole tutorial from scratch. Eliminating the project and starting another.

Comment: It's normal. "add field..." reveals if you will make models.py with Choice model without question field, then make migrations, then apply it, then add question field, make another migration and apply it

Comment: While reading this question, I found out this observation on the tutorial: "The exact output will vary depending on the database you are using. **The example above is generated for PostgreSQL.**"  I think it's related that we ran the example using SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are saying that when you ran `python manage.py makemigrations polls`, you expected the following output, based on the tutorial:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Question
    - Add field question to choice
```

but instead, you got the following output:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice
```

You need not be concerned with the missing `- Add field question to choice` output. You didn't encounter an error & everything seems to be in order. Continue with the tutorial. You'll soon migrate the model tables to your database & then [play with the api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api). As long as you get the expected output when you are exploring the API in the shell, then everything is working fine.

As a general matter, it is good to keep in mind that the terminal output shown in tutorials may differ slightly based on a wide variety of factors, so if things don't match up exactly, just make sure that the actual functionality that you were implementing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same,
i was learning from an online tutorial,
and i saw his 0001_initial.py file in migrations folder
mine had addfield missing, so i copied it.
It now shows the same result.
Delete the operations and paste this instead:

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Question',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('question_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date published')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Choice',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('choice_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('votes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('question', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Question')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='choice',
        name='question',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Question'),
        preserve_default=True
    )
]
```